# Where is this shot of Takodana taken from?

Tags: star-wars, film-location, the-force-awakens

I was watching *The Force Awakens* and got to the bit where the Millennium Falcon comes swooping into Takodana. I have a very strong suspicion that I know this skyline, particularly this hills in the mid distance on the left and right.

[image]

Is there any official word on it if any real life location was used for this scene or is it simply a huge coincidence that it looks like somewhere I know?

Comment: I'm in two minds to post a comment/answer of where I think it is - what do people think?

Comment: Does the answer match your expectation? You got me curious

Comment: Awesome, good eye for detail

Comment: @m1gp0z - not really, I've seen that skyline hundreds of times and have climbed almost every hill in that photo. The real fun starts when you try to work out where the lake district stops and the CG begins!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This shot was taken at the Lake District.

From [Atlas of Wonders](https://www.atlasofwonders.com/2015/12/filming-locations-force-awakens-star.html)

> The Millennium Falcon flying over the Lake District. In the movie this is the planet Takodana, where the cantina is located.

Also from [IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2488496/locations),

> Derwentwater, Lake District, Cumbria, England, UK
>
> (Approach to Maz Kanata's Castle, Takodana)